# How do I set webpack mode

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm trying to configure my script (in package.json) in such a way that I can run webpack in production or development mode via cli.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack serve",
"build": "webpack --mode=production"
```

in my webpack.config.js file, I was expecting `process.env.NODE_ENV` to equal to whatever I set the mode to be. Instead, I keep getting `undefined` please how can I make it work

Comment: Are you trying to setup two different command lines for running a webpack dev server and for generating a production build?

Comment: yes, that's what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2):

**For the Dev Server**

First, install webpack-dev-server with following command:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

Add following line to the package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
}
```

**For Production build**
Add the following line to the scripts section of package.json:

```
"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production"
```

The scripts section in package.json with both the dev and production build will look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development" 
}
```